# IntelliJ IDEA: Element jsp:root is not allowed here

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

The `<jsp:root>` element of my JSP files is displayed in red color in IntelliJ IDEA and when I hover over it the "Element jsp:root is not allowed here" message appears.

The JSP files of the project start like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"/>
```

How can I resolve this warning?

Comment: Did you try without the `jsp:`i.e. `<root xmlns:` ... ? I didn't try it but it looks similar to a problem with `beans:bean` and `<bean `.. that I had in IntelliJ.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it disabled the markup validation feature of JSP. Now if I forget to close a tag I don't get an error anymore. Still looking for a viable solution.